# how can i use an array to make random circles

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, paintcomponent

I have been working on a school assignment and the teacher wants us to make 7 circles appear on a JPanel and move downwards. Once a circle reaches the bottom a new circle should be made to replace the circle that reached the bottom of the JPanel. I decided to use an array to continue to make random circles but I cant get it to work right. I used a for loop to populate the array with circles that have a random radius and color. The code compiles but when I run it I get an exception. I am having a hard time getting the array to work properly. The other thing that I am not sure about is how to draw the circles so that they are space out across the JPanel.

The Code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class keyExample extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private Circle[] circles = new Circle[7];

    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
//current x and y
    double x = 150, y = 200;
    double changeX = 0, changeY = 0;
    private Circle;
    private int circlex = 0, circley = 0; // makes initial starting point of circles 0
    private javax.swing.Timer timer2;

    public keyExample() {

        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);


        }

        timer2 = new javax.swing.Timer(33, new MoveListener());
        timer2.start();

    }

    public void NewCircle() {
        Random colors = new Random();
        Color color = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));

        Random num = new Random();
        int radius = num.nextInt(45);

        for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            circles[i] = new Circle(circlex, circley, radius, color);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
        NewCircle();
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++)
        circles[i].fill(g);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        x += changeX;
        y += changeY;
        changeX = 0;
        changeY = 0;

    }

    public void up() {
        if (y != 0) {
            changeY = -3.5;
            changeX = 0;
        }
    }

    public void down() {
        if (y <= 350) {
            changeY = 3.5;
            changeX = 0;

        }
    }

    public void left() {
        if (x >= 0) {
            changeX = -3.5;
            changeY = 0;
        }
    }

    public void right() {
        if (x <= 550) {
            changeX = 3.5;
            changeY = 0;
        }
    }

    private class MoveListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            repaint();
            Random speed = new Random();
            int s = speed.nextInt(8);
            circle.move(0, s);
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: I added the exception above the code. It continues to print out that exception until I close the program.

Comment: circle (which you try and access within paintComponent) is null

Comment: Make it non-null before you try to paint with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to paint with the circle variable, a variable that you never assign a valid reference to.

One solution is to give it a valid reference via `circle = new Circle(...)`, but having said that, I'll tell you to ignore it since you shouldn't even be using the variable circle. Just get rid of it. What you want to do is to use your **circles** array -- that's what you should be painting in your paintComponent method. Use a for loop inside of paintComponent and iterate through the array painting each circle item that the array holds.

Comment: i edited my code to show what i did to fix the problem. I made a new method called NewCircle() that uses the for loop to fill the array with random circles. I then called that method when using the paint component. Now the problem im having is spacing out the circles across the JPanel

Comment: @user3076906: That's a new problem and should be a new question.

Comment: ok but there are still a few things i am unsure of. 1) spacing out the circles across the JPanel. 2) how to keep making new circles to when one of the circles reaches the bottom of the screen. 3) how to make all of the circles move downwards

Comment: @user3076906: and you should solve each problem, one at a time, in isolation of the others.